# counter for attempts in c#

Tags: c#, counter

I am trying to get the counter named "Guesses" to keep a tally of attempts at guessing a random number and output the total attempts at guessing the number. I have tried leaving the counter declaration at 0 and 1 and the number of attempts to guess is always 0 or 1. Help would be appreciated and I will re-post entire working code once it's figured out. Here is my code.

```
    int Answer; // declares the Answer variable outside button event
    public frmGuess()
    {  // generates random number outside button event so does not change on button click
        InitializeComponent();
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        Answer = rand.Next(100) + 1; // makes it range 1 to 100
    }
    private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int UserGuess;
        int Guesses = 0;     // start counter
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGuess.Text)) // input validation check to make sure not blank and is a whole number integer
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number between 1 and 100");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            UserGuess = int.Parse(txtGuess.Text);  // variable assign and code run
            Guesses ++;
            if (UserGuess > Answer)
            {
                txtGuess.Text = "";
                lblAnswer.Text = "Too high, try again.";
            }
            else if (UserGuess < Answer)
            {
                txtGuess.Text = "";
                lblAnswer.Text = "Too low, try again.";
            }
            else
            {
                lblAnswer.Text = "Congratulations the answer was " + Answer + "!\nYou guessed the number in " + Guesses + " tries.\nTo play again click the clear button."; //victory statement
            }//end if
        } //end if
    } 
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // clears Answer label and Guess textbox
    {
        txtGuess.Text = "";
        lblAnswer.Text = "";
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // closes window
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: You're resetting the counter every time you enter the button click event.  Make it a class level variable, initialize it at start and increment it in the button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting the counter in your click event.

```
int Answer; // declares the Answer variable outside button event
int Guesses = 0; // declare this outside button event, and initialize it to 0.
                 // initialization will happen when the Form object is created.

...

private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int UserGuess;
    // DO NOT reset the counter here. This line is the culprit that
    // resets the counter every time you click the button
    //int Guesses = 0;     // start counter
    ...
} 

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed! That took care of it. To think I placed the random number outside the button click but didn't do it to the counter - foolishness. Thanks all!  Working code is :

```
{
    int Answer; // declares the Answer variable outside button event
    int Guesses = 0;     // declares counter outside button event
    public frmGuess()
    { // generates random number outside button event so does not change on button click
        InitializeComponent();
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        Answer = rand.Next(100) + 1; // makes it range 1 to 100
    }
    private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int UserGuess;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtGuess.Text)) // input validation check to make sure not blank and is a whole number integer
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number between 1 and 100");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            UserGuess = int.Parse(txtGuess.Text);  // variable assign and code run

            Guesses ++; // adds 1 to attempts but doesn't count textbox blank or mistyping

            if (UserGuess > Answer)
            {
                txtGuess.Text = "";
                lblAnswer.Text = "Too high, try again.";
                Guesses++;
            }
            else if (UserGuess < Answer)
            {
                txtGuess.Text = "";
                lblAnswer.Text = "Too low, try again.";
                Guesses++;
            }
            else
            {
                lblAnswer.Text = "Congratulations the answer was " + Answer + "!\nYou guessed the number in " + Guesses + " tries.\nTo play again click the clear button.";
            }//end if
        } //end if
    } 
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // clears Answer label and Guess textbox
    {
        txtGuess.Text = "";
        lblAnswer.Text = "";
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // closes window
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

It's a scoping issue. You currently define guesses within your event handler where it resets the counter with each button click. If you define it at the form level, even as a property or member variable, that scope will allow the variable to retain its value through multiple button click events.